# Is it possible to count the citations that a paper has received in a particular country using Web of Science?

Tags: citations, bibliometrics

I'm new in the use of bibliometrics. I was wondering if you can help me out? Consider this situation, an author "x" of the country "c" , publishes a paper "p" with a(n) international collaborator(s). If I want to know how many citations does the paper "p" has received from the country "c", is that possible? Is that so, three situations can happen.

One is that "only" author(s) of "c" cited "p", in which I will count 1. The second case is that there is a mix between author(s) of the country "c" and international authors, in which I will count a fraction of the authors belonging to "c" divided by the total authors of the paper that is citing "p". The third case is that only papers with international authors are citing "p", that I will count 0.

Answer (score 3):

WoS allows you to look at all the papers citing a given paper P, and there is a link to "Analyze Results", where country is one of the options. (It defaults to a minimum count of 2; you'll want to drop this to 1)

For a randomly selected paper from a recent search, here's an example:

[image]

There are 11 citing papers; of these, seven have at least one US author, two at least one Czech author, etc. This would give a value of 0.64 if your original author was American, or 0.18 if they were Czech.

The obvious downside is that you need to do this for each paper P; you can't do it automatically for a hundred at once. But it's a start...

---

**Edit**: you can do this through Scopus as well. Select the paper, find citing papers, "analyse search results", and you get this:

Here, there are a total of three papers citing P, two of which have German author(s), one Austrian, etc.

[image]

With Scopus, you *can* do the analysis for a large group of papers, but it won't help you very much. From your initial search result, select all items using the checkbox, and click "view cited by". Then analyse search results again, and you get the stats for all papers citing one or more of the original search results. However, this won't help answer your question as to %age of papers with overseas citations - they're all bundled together and not segregated by cited paper.

Comment: You are the best, I will have to do this for a large volume of papers... So I need to find a way to automatize it... I heard that people can write scripts to do it... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible with WOS.  You can use the WOS API.  Using python it is very simple to download the data and make specific queries.  The data can be fetched with SOAP as an XML format document.  You can then parse it with a few lines of code to extract the data you want by searching the address fields of the citations.

You can get started here: http://ip-science.thomsonreuters.com/m/pdfs/wos_workbook_en.pdf

Comment: It's important to note that the standard WoS/WoK API only provides basic metadata for a given article, and it no longer includes citation metadata - http://wokinfo.com/products_tools/products/related/webservices/ws_faq/ . For the citation data, you need the premium service. It seems this is now available with an InCites subscription. http://www.eprints.org/tech.php/17932.html

Comment: @Andrew , If you are using through a university IP, you are almost always going to have the premium service.